# Как преобразовать список со словарями внутри в строку

Tags: python, list, словари, список, словарь

Имеется такой список

```
['Текст в списке вне словаря', {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 1'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 1'}, {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 2'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 2'}, {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 3'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 3'}, 'Текст вне словаря']
```

Как всё это преобразовать в обычную строку?

Так же стоит проверить, есть ли словари в списке

Я пытался различными методами конвертировать список в строку, но из-за словарей внутри, у меня не получилось

Comment: а какую строку вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: @Zhihar просто переменная типа str без всех скобочек

Comment: "Текст в списке вне словаря Индекс 1 Элемент 1 Индекс 2 Элемент 2" - такой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы проверить, есть ли в списке словари можно сделать такой код:

```
data = ['Текст в списке вне словаря', {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 1'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 1'}, {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 2'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 2'}, {'Индекс 1': 'Элемент 3'}, {'Индекс 2': 'Элемент 3'}, 'Текст вне словаря']

dict_enabled = any(type(obj) == type(dict()) for obj in data)

print(dict_enabled)
```

естественно код не рекурсивный, т.е. считаем, что если в списке и есть словарь, то он является элементом списка, а не элементом элемента списка например

На счет перевода в строку - не понял, нужен вот такой код:

```
res = []
for obj in data:
    if type(obj) == type(str()):
        res.append(obj)
    elif type(obj) == type(dict()):
        for key in obj:
            res += [key, obj[key]]


text = ' '.join(res)
print(text)
```